# Cannot Lint my TypeScript project using @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin and eslint.config.js flat config

Tags: node.js, typescript, eslint

I'd like to migrate from `.eslintrc.json` to `eslint.config.js` before the config is deprecated in `ESLint v9.0.0`. I went through the reasons behind the [change](https://eslint.org/blog/2022/08/new-config-system-part-2/#main), which I found well-founded.

Here my new `eslint.config.js` with some basic options:

```js
const typeScriptEslintParser = require('@typescript-eslint/parser');
const typeScriptEsLintPlugin = require('@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin');
const esLintConfigPrettier = require('eslint-config-prettier');

module.exports = [
  "eslint:recommended",
  typeScriptEsLintPlugin.configs.recommended,
  esLintConfigPrettier,
  {
    languageOptions: {
      parser: typeScriptEslintParser,
      parserOptions: {
        ecmaVersion: 'latest',
        sourceType: 'module',
      },
    },
    plugins: {
      '@typescript-eslint': typeScriptEsLintPlugin,
    },
    rules: {
      '@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars': 'error',

    },
  },
];
```

The `.eslintrc.json` normally extends from `eslint:recommended` and `plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended`. When I try to add the config exported by `@typescript-eslint/recommended` to `eslint.config.js`, I got the following error:

```
ESLint: Error: Key "extends": This appears to be in eslintrc format rather than flat config format.
```

Lastly, regarding IDE support, WebStorm looks automatically for `.eslintrc.*` files. How would this situation change with the new flat config?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did to solve the issue,

1. `npm i --save-dev @eslint/eslintrc`
2. Import `FlatCompat` into your `eslint.config.js` from the [`@eslint/eslintrc`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@eslint/eslintrc) package.
3. Create and configure a `compat` wrapper out of `FlatCompat` for translating your ESLintRC-style configs into flat configs.
4. The `compat` wrapper should translate the configuration exported by `@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin` to the corresponding flat-config object.

After going through all steps, I ended up wit the following `eslint.config.json`:

```js
const typeScriptEsLintPlugin = require('@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin');
const esLintConfigPrettier = require('eslint-config-prettier');
const { FlatCompat } = require('@eslint/eslintrc');

// Translate ESLintRC-style configs into flat configs.
const compat = new FlatCompat({
  baseDirectory: __dirname,
  recommendedConfig: typeScriptEsLintPlugin.configs['recommended'],
});

module.exports = [
  // ESLint recommended flat config.
  'eslint:recommended',

  // Flat config for parsing TypeScript files. Includes rules for TypeScript.
  ...compat.config({
    env: { node: true },
    extends: ['plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended'],
    parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
    parserOptions: {
      ecmaVersion: 'latest',
      sourceType: 'module',
    },
    plugins: ['@typescript-eslint'],
    rules: {
      '@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars': 'error',
      '@typescript-eslint/no-empty-interface': 'error',
    },
  }),

  // Flat config for turning off all rules that are unnecessary or might conflict with Prettier.
  esLintConfigPrettier,

  // Flat config for ESLint rules.
  {
    rules: {
      camelcase: ['error', { ignoreDestructuring: true }],
    },
  },
];
```

There are some takeaways:

- The `compat` wrapper should know about the configuration you'd like to translate. If your configuration extends from `eslint:recommended`, then you should provide `recommendedConfig` to the `FlatCompat` constructor. Otherwise, you would get:

> ESLint: TypeError: Missing parameter 'recommendedConfig' in FlatCompat constructor.

- `eslint-config-prettier` doesn't need any translation as it exports a compatible flat-config object.
- `eslint:recommended` is already available as flat config. Though you might get the following warning when using `module.exports` syntax:

> ESLint: 'module' is not defined.(no-undef)

This is fixable if you define `node:true` as env var. According to the docs, this issue was resolved by using `sourceType: 'module'` in the `parserOptions` object in `eslint.config.js`. Unfortunately, I couldn't get rid of the error that way.

- I isolated all TypeScript-ESLint in a independent flat-config. You might also have a flat-config just for the parser options using the `languageOptions` prop. There is much flexibility when doing overriding of flat-configs. Use what it makes sense to you.
- Do NOT re-declare the same plugin in multiple flat-configs or you'd get errors.

Answer (score 0):

Either `@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin` or `eslint-config-prettier` provides config in the `eslintrc` format rather then in `eslint.config.js` format

You are going to need to replace them (possibly with `@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin/eslint.config.js` if there's one) or wrap into compatibility function, see https://eslint.org/blog/2022/08/new-config-system-part-2/#backwards-compatibility-utility

```
import { FlatCompat } from "@eslint/eslintrc";
const compat = new FlatCompat(...);

export default [
    // mimic ESLintRC-style extends
    ...compat.extends("standard", "example"),
]
```